# Переход по ссылке при изменении в листе

Tags: google-apps-script

Мне нужно чтобы при любом изменении в листе sheet1 осуществлялся переход по ссылке. У меня имеется следующий код:

```
function onEdit(e){
var changedSheet = e.range.getSheet();
var sheet = 'sheet1';
if(changedSheet.getName()===sheet){
    var link = "<script> window.open('https://www.google.com/');</script>";
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(link)
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html,'Loading...');
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close();</script>');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Close...');
    }
}
```

Подскажите, каким образом заставить код работать.

Comment: Не лучший вариант поведения. Из `onEdit` вообще невозможно, если это простой триггер.

Answer (score 0):

Решил похожую проблему так.
Открывается sidebar на пару сек, и после закрывается:

```
var js = "<script> document.location.href = 'tel:"+repla+"'; google.script.host.close(); </script>";
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
```